# Custom ImageButton, which method to override for simplest RadioButton interface?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-custom-view, ontouchlistener, android-imagebutton

I am in the process of making a custom view that is essentially an ImageButton with added logic so it also have the behavior of a RadioButton. All I want to do is have it built into the view that when the user clicks the button the image is changed, an internal boolean is marked true to note it is selected, and an interface method is called to let the RadioGroup it is a part of to unselect all the other views within it. **I don't want to impact the existing behavior of the base ImageButton whatsoever.**

I've only made one other custom view before and that was by following a tutorial almost exactly to the letter and since there are so many different methods inhereted from View that deal with clicks/touches (i.e. onTouch, onClick, motion event, etc.) taking it all in has left me a bit confused. I am fine writing the interface itself, its the modification of ImageButton where I'm not too sure how to attack it.

So, I ask you all: What method/methods do I need to override to add this simple functionality, while not impacting the current behavior of ImageButton, nor screwing up the ability to set an onTouchListener for the button that will perform additional actions on click without compromising this built in radio button logic? If I need to override something that will mess with the default behavior I mentioned, what do I need to put in the new method to restore that functionality?

This is what I have so far:

```
public class RadioImageButton extends AppCompatImageButton implements RadioCheckable {

//Default constructor
public RadioImageButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView();
}

//Constructor with defined attributes
public RadioImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    parseAttributes();
    initView();
}

//Constructor with defined attributes and attributes taken from style defaults that aren't defined
public RadioImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}



//=========================================================================
// Setup
//=========================================================================

private void initView()
{

}

private void parseAttributes()
{

}
```

}

The approach I would like to take would be something like:

```
...All other code I already showed

mChecked = false;

@Overide
void onClick(...)
{
       mChecked = true;
       setImageSource(R.example.checked_image); // Or I can use a selector resource
       *Call to Radio Interface*;
       mOnTouchListener.onTouch(v, event); //Handle user onTouchListener
}
...
```

and leave all the other code alone, though I'm sure it isn't quite that simple.

I thought a good start would be trying to find the source code for the default ImageButton class and set mine up to be a near replica so I can understand how it works and then modify from there, but all I could really find was this:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.0.0_r35/core/java/android/widget/ImageButton.java

and there is no way that is the actual source because pressing Ctrl+O shows many more functions that ImageButton defines that are not inherited from another class; regardless, that link is not at all helpful as its basically a giant comment with little to no code.

Thanks for any suggestions that will help me accomplish this in the most straightforward way.

**EDIT:** @pskink - Looking through the code you provided, it seems like it is trying to generate a matrix in order to transform the provided drawable (src) so that it fits into a new rectangle (dst) while maintaining the aspect ratio and positioning (hence ScaleToFit.CENTER). I would assume the destination rectangle would be the bounds of the view the drawable is contained in, which in this case is the RadioButton, but while stepping through the override of the "draw()" method it doesn't quite seem to be doing that, though I'm not quite sure how cavas.concat(matrix) is resolved so I'm not positive. Regardless it doesn't seem to work as intended or I am somehow using it wrong.

Comment: It might be clearer if you have a look at the code for [`CompoundButton`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/CompoundButton.java), which is the super class for `RadioButton`. However, `RadioGroup` only works with `RadioButton`s, so you'll either have to write your own `ViewGroup` or separate logic for the single selection, or subclass `RadioButton` instead, and integrate those features of `ImageButton`/`ImageView` that you're trying to utilize.

Comment: use normal `RadioButton` - in fact you dont even have to extend it - all you have to write is a custom `Drawable` (most likely extending `StateListDrawable` ?) and use it with `View#setBackground()` method

Comment: @pskink   I'm pretty sure they're trying take advantage of `ImageView`'s/`ImageButton`'s built-in scaling modes. Have a look at their previous question. That's why they'd have to subclass `RadioButton`, if they go that route.

Comment: @MikeM. yes indeed, you are the real Sherlock Holmes, i  could not even think about finding previous questions.... ;-)

Comment: @MikeM. but actually i saw some 3rd party code that mimics all `ImageView`'s scale types into transformed `Matrix` so the only thing you really need is a custom `Drawable` where only the presentation is changed depending of scale type - something like [this](https://github.com/yqritc/Android-ScalableImageView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/yqritc/scalableimageview/ScaleManager.java)

Comment: @pskink Ah, that's one I didn't think of. Nice. Much cleaner than trying to overhaul `RadioButton` in a subclass.

Comment: @MikeM. and that code can be simplified a lot as they dont use `Matrix.setRectToRect` which is very handy

Comment: @pskink (and MikeM) That does look like it could be quite useful, though I very much want the buttons image to look sized correctly in the designer xml, which wouldn't be achieved with this as I'd have to utilize this manager during the onCreate() method of the parent activity right?

Comment: Or perhaps I could subclass RaidoButton and use this manager to rescale the background image or button graphic in the custom views constructor while leaving everything else alone? Though I'm not sure if that will also show up in the designer correctly.

Comment: if you want to see it correctly in the designer then yes, you would need to extend `RaidoButton` and override `onDraw` method (but i am not sure, maybe there are some more clever ways, i dont know)

Comment: but if you want to use std `RadioButton` try [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/5y45rTB7) custom `Drawable` - you have to pass resId pointing to some existing [<selector>](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList) drawable defining your multiple drawables

Comment: and? do you know how it works? of course if you dont want to write any xml `<selector>` drawable you can directly use `StateListDrawable#addState` in the constructor

Comment: @pskink - To try it out I used a test layout with a RadioGroup and two RadioButtons. Declared "D scaledDrawable" and then in the test activity's onCreate() method I instantiated it by doing "scaledDrawable = new D(getResources(),R.drawable.test_draw)" where the drawable is a selector. I then put a button in the same layout that on click performs "radioButtonTest.setButtonDrawable(scaledDrawable)". This correctly changes the default button to use my two drawables specified in the selector, but it doesn't seem to scale it at all unfortunately. Can edit original question with more info if needed.

Comment: ok i tested that with a `Button` which is easier to test, see https://pastebin.com/2eK10Xui - most likely the difference is in using `setButtonDrawable`

Comment: @pskink - Thanks for the persistence. I will try that out on my side to confirm it works in that case on my end and if so I will try editing the background drawable of the radio button and setting the button drawable to transparent to see if that works.

Comment: @pskink - It does work with the RadioButton background, "setButtonDrawable" messes it up for some reason. I will most likely try to make use of this or the 3rd party matrix code you linked to. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While maybe not the most robust method, it seems like the most straightforward, yet effective way to handle what I wanted to do was to leverage the Matrix class and its powerful scaling/transformation tools, specifically "setRectToRect()". Creating a custom view that extends RadioButton instead of ImageButton allowed me to make use of the existing RadioGroup, while manipulating characteristics of the button's drawables in the new classes Constructor achieved the behavior I was looking for.

Custom RadioButton class:

```
public class RadioImageButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton {

    int stateDrawable; //Resource ID for RadioButton selector Drawable
    D scaledDrawable; //Post-scaling drawable

    public RadioImageButtonTwo(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public RadioImageButtonTwo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        parseAttributes(attrs);
        initView();
    }


    private void parseAttributes(AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        TypedArray styledAttrs = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.RadioImageButtonTwo);
        try {
            // Obtain selector drawable from attributes
            stateDrawable = styledAttrs.getResourceId(R.styleable.RadioImageButtonTwo_button_sDrawable, R.drawable.test_draw2);
        } finally {
            styledAttrs.recycle(); //Required for public shared view
        }

    }

    private void initView()
    {
        scaledDrawable = new D(getResources(),stateDrawable); // Create scaled drawable
        setBackground(scaledDrawable); // Apply scaled drawable
        setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent); // "Disable" button graphic
    }
}
```

See more on setting up a custom view here: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr

Custom drawable class "D" that includes fitCenter scaling thanks to @pskink:

```
class D extends StateListDrawable {
    private Rect bounds = new Rect();
    private RectF src = new RectF();
    private RectF dst = new RectF();
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    public D(Resources r, int resId) {
        try {
            XmlResourceParser parser = r.getXml(resId);
            int type;
            while ((type = parser.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (type == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("selector")) {
                    inflate(r, parser, Xml.asAttributeSet(parser));
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable current = getCurrent();
        bounds.set(0, 0, current.getIntrinsicWidth(), current.getIntrinsicHeight());
        current.setBounds(bounds);

        src.set(bounds);
        dst.set(getBounds());
        matrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

        canvas.concat(matrix);
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Note that for whatever reason setting the button drawable itself to this custom drawable breaks the scaling, so changing the background to the custom drawable and setting the button drawable to transparent was the only way this worked. This custom drawable could easily be expanded upon to have more scaling type options and another view attribute could be defined to allow the user to choose the scaling type through XML.

This custom ImageView that mimics the (pointed out by pskink aswell) could also prove helpful in this task, as it too utilizes the Matrix class to implement multiple types of image scaling:  https://github.com/yqritc/Android-ScalableImageView

Comment: if you are extending `RadioButton` there is no need to use that custom `D` drawable, see: https://pastebin.com/raw/W04G8pjy

Comment: Lol. Back at it again. I'll switch to this when I'm back at home in a few days and update the answer. This definitively is a bit simpler since the drawable scaling is part of the RadioButton class and now independent. Thanks again.

Comment: and instead of using `ScaleManager` you could use the [easier version](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java#1219) - this is how `ImageView` calulates its `mDrawMatrix` (of course you would need to change the code a bit but its 15 minutes work)

Comment: this [simplified code](https://pastebin.com/raw/8k5JVfCR) computes all the `ImageView.ScaleType`s - i did not test all the cases (where src is smaller and bigger then dst) but i think it should work :-)

Comment: @pskink Too helpful :)

Comment: @pskink sorry I haven't had a chance to try it yet because the Radio Button code framework you supplied has been more than adequate so at the moment I'm focusing on other issues.